# Why does .split in python not work on double bracket list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand why a double bracket list throws an error when using .split().
If I can't get rid of the double brackets, what are other ways to split both double and single bracket lists?

**example :**

```
y = (['3801 - 2', '123 + 49'])
print(type(y))
for i in y:
    print(i.split(' '))
```

**output:**

```
<class 'list'>
['3801', '-', '2']
['123', '+', '49']
```

**While**

```
x = ([['3801 - 2', '123 + 49']])
print(type(x))
for i in x:
    print(i.split(' '))
```

**output:**

```
<class 'list'>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: It's not a "double bracket list", it's a list with another list inside. Lists have no `split()` method, so... there you are.

Comment: `y = (['3801 - 2', '123 + 49'])` Those parentheses are doing literally nothing.  They might as well not be there.  This is NOT a list inside of a tuple.

Comment: when you use for loop you iterate through some strings in first example - string do have split method. in second example you iterate through some lists which don't have that method and that's what error message says.

Comment: No such thing as a "double bracket list". It's a list within a list. Lists can't be split — what would even be a sensible result?

Comment: To expand on @JohnGordon's comment, if the first example had a trailing comma inside the (), then it would be a tuple.   
`y = (['3801 - 2', '123 + 49'], )` `type(y)`  would output `<class 'tuple'>`, and then you would get the AttributeError as seen in the second example.

Comment: Also pointing out that the parentheses used in the assignment to *y* are redundant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because then you have a list inside a list.
The iteration unravels only the outermost list, whose only element is another list (that does not support the split method).

You either use a nested loop:

```py
for j in y:
    for i in j:
        i.split()
```

or access the first element:

```py
for i in y[0]:
    i.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

the split method is for string

In the first case you loop in the list and split the string inside

In the second case you loop in the list that contain another list so you try to split that list and not the string inside. And that's a mistake because list can't be split.

A list is already splitted :)